# Using facebook sdk on android, is there a way to send a message without user prompt?

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

Using the `Facebook SDK`, I want to send a message without prompting the user. Can someone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A rooted device will not prompt user for permissions.